# SR9700 Core Chips driver for Xubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, xubuntu, ethernet

I have usb to ethernet adapter by Core Chips. In my Xubuntu I can't get ethernet connection. lsusb or ip commands dosn't show me any informations.

```
➜  ~ lsusb
     Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
     Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
     Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
     Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:385a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
     Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
     Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:2403 A4Tech Co., Ltd. 2.4G Device
     Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0fe6:9702 ICS Advent Bluetooth Radio
     Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
     Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Please any solutions)

Comment: Do they have a Ubuntu driver for it? You also never said what version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank's for attention for my question. My Xubuntu version is 20.04.

Comment: I have this link http://www.corechip-sz.com/endownload.asp?classid=98 but I can't download any drivers. I wrote to support today.

Comment: With the device inserted, please run the command: `lsusb` and edit your question to show the result. dm9601??

Comment: I added lsusb output.

Comment: Where can I get source files for sr9700 driver? Maybe I can replace device id in source and rebuild it..

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any Core Chips SR9700 device in your lsusb. Was it inserted??

Comment: It's 0fe6:9702 device but ID isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the 0fe6:9702, but it is very ugly.  However, it will get you a temporary, slow Ethernet port.

Disclaimer: This will taint your kernel.  You will have to redo this every time you upgrade your kernel.  I could not get it to work at 100, only 10/Half.
(English: It's not kosher, upgrades will break it, and it's VERY slow)

Leave the adapter unplugged.  First, we made a backup of the driver.

```
cp /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/usb/dm9601.ko dm9601.ko.orig
```

Next, we modify the driver:

```
xxd /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/usb/dm9601.ko | sed 's/e60f 0097/e60f 0297/g' | xxd -r > dm9601.ko.mod
```

Then, we strip it.

```
strip --strip-debug dm9601.ko.mod
```

Then we copy the modified driver

```
sudo cp dm9601.ko.mod /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/usb/dm9601.ko
```

Last, we load the modified kernel module

```
sudo modprobe -r dm9601 && sudo modprobe dm9601
```

Now, this is important, plug the Ethernet in BEFORE plugging in the USB.  If you don't, it won't work.  Lastly, use your preferred tool to bring the interface up.  Personally, I like the command line "nmtui" which, if you use, you likely will have to select "Activate a connection," then select the usb Ethernet, arrow over to "Deactivate" to deactivate it, then activate it again the same way.  After all this - you should have a working Ethernet adapter.

Things that don't work:
I could not get it working at 100Mbs nor full duplex.  Ethtool has zero effect on it.  Yes, I did try compiling ndsiwrapper.  Yeah, with new patches.  No, ndiswrapper does not work.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.